# NSFetchedResultsController custom behavior upon empty results

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a single section table view which is hooked up to a NSFetchedResultsController. When the results from the core data is empty and under some extra conditions I would like to create a custom row which contents will be provided not by CoreData. Is there a clean way of implementing this with the NSFetchedResultsController?

Comment: What will this one placeholder row display?  It might be more appropriate to implement it in the respective `UITableView`'s dataSource method -- subclassing the `NSFetchedResultsController` might do the wrong thing if, down the line, you start using that object to service many views.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `NSFetchedResultsController` does not offer a feature like that. Just implement your table data source to check how many `fetchedObjects` the FRC has and use that to decide if the rows of the table should be provided by the FRC or you should instead show your custom empty row.

Comment: +1 this isn't a responsibilty that FRC should have. This should be owned by the TableView controller